# Does the visreg2d function in R do any transformation of the z variable values?

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot the following model in the visreg2d function:

```
df:
    z     x         y
3   18 2.317 1.3469362
5   20 2.729 1.5302024
7   54 4.390 1.4901918
10  63 3.260 1.5699884
11  44 7.695 1.3343464
12  79 4.670 1.5835897
13  45 4.776 1.5689444
14 112 5.746 1.5391921
15  62 4.372 1.2934900
16  30 2.791 1.3452693
17 104 1.947 1.2657156
18  64 5.992 1.2602159
20   6 4.978 1.4450156
21  27 5.319 0.8372051
22   4 0.646 1.1897316
23  38 6.098 1.1664697
24  21 5.558 0.9362094
26  24 5.338 0.7679927
29   3 7.749 1.3922017
30   2 7.402 1.2852814

m1<-gam(z~x+y,df, family="poisson")

visreg2d(m1,x="x",y="y",z="z", plot.type="gg") +
theme_classic()
```

Problem:
The z-axis scale does not match what is provided in the dataframe. Does the visreg2d function in R do any transformation of the z variable values?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x08N.png)

I would like the z-axis of the visreg2d function plot to show the values ​​corresponding to those given in the dataframe.